# mysqli select/search names that have and don't have sapces

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am wanting to echo rows where the column 'tipster' is equal to the form input option the user chooses.

I have tried `replace (tipster ' '. '') LIKE '$tipster'` and it did not return any results... Some fields have spaces in the name whilst some don't - e.g. `'John Jones Smith'`, `'John Jones'` and `'JohnJones'`.... I need to search the column that matches the option chosen in the html form (check the rows with and without spaces)

If I Just do a single word search (e.g. Example)...the result comes back fine as its **LIKE** query. I would like to comment that the GET function works but is passing the input as example+one in the url....not sure if the + is effecting the mysqli result potentially?

**HTML**

```
 <form id="tipster_search" method="get" action="example.php">               
      <label for="tipster">Select Tipster</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="tipster" id="tipster">
          <option>Example One</option>
          <option>ExampleTwo</option>
          <option>Example Option Three</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-info" name="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
function processForm() {
    $tipster = $_GET['tipster'];
    $url = "example.php?tipster=".$tipster."";
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

$tipster = $_GET['tipster'];
$q = "SELECT * FROM bets WHERE `tipster` LIKE '%$tipster%' ORDER BY betDate DESC LIMIT 25";
$query = mysqli_query($connection,$q);
$x = 1;
echo "<table class='table'><tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>Bet Date</th>";
echo "<th>Tipster</th>";
echo "<th>Sport</th>";
echo "<th>Meeting</th>";
echo "<th>Time</th>";
echo "<th>Stake Name</th>";
echo "<th>Odds</th>";
echo "<th>Stake Type</th>";
echo "<th>Stake Placed</th>";
echo "<th>Result</th>";
echo "<th>Return</th>";
echo "<th>Profit</th>";

if($query === FALSE) { 
    die(mysqli_error($connection)); // better error handling
}

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $res['id'];
    $betDate = $res['betDate'];
    $tipster = $res['tipster'];
    $sport = $res['sport'];
    $meeting = $res['meeting'];
    $time = $res['time'];
    $stakeName = $res['stakeName'];
    $odds = $res['odds'];
    $stakeType = $res['stakeType'];
    $stakePlaced = $res['stakePlaced'];
    $result = $res['result'];
    $return = $res['return'];
    $profit = $res['profit'];

    echo "<tr><td><p>$id</p></td>"; 
    echo "<td><p>$betDate</p></td>";
    echo "<td><p>$tipster</p></td>"; 
    echo "<td><p>$sport</p></td>"; 
    echo "<td><p>$meeting</p></td>";
    echo "<td><p>$time</p></td>"; 
    echo "<td><p>$stakeName</p></td>"; 
    echo "<td><p>$odds</p></td>";
    echo "<td><p>$stakeType</p></td>";
    echo "<td><p>&pound;$stakePlaced</p></td>"; 
    echo "<td><p>$result</p></td>"; 
    echo "<td><p>&pound;$return</p></td>";
    echo "<td><p>&pound;$profit</p></td></tr>";

}
?>
```

Comment: How about: `WHERE REPLACE(tipster, ' ', '') LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE($tipster, ' ', ''), '%')` ?

Comment: I shall give it a go @GMB

Comment: @GMB  - clicked Example One from drop down then got this - _You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'One, ' ', ''),_

Comment: Sorry: `WHERE REPLACE(tipster, ' ', '') LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('$tipster', ' ', ''), '%')`. NB: you should consider using parameterized query to protect your code against SQL injections...

Comment: Thanks! it works, brilliant :)

Comment: Nice! Let me post this as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
WHERE REPLACE(tipster, ' ', '') LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('$tipster', ' ', ''), '%')
```

NB: anyone on SO will strongly suggest to **[use prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**, to protect your code from SQL injection and make your queries more readable and maintainable. Such typo is far much easier to detect when using parameterized queries.